# simple_form undefined method `model_name' for NilClass:Class

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, simple-form

I'm learning Rails, and I would like to use simple_form.
I'm creating a simple app (my first one), and I want to create a signup form.
I used rails g scaffold User username:string password:string to create my model and controller.
I'm using Foundation gem too, if that's matter, and I install simple_form with the right command for Foundation.
I've been looking for answers for two hours, I tried many things, I have no idea of what's wrong with my code.

```
## app/views/home/index.html.erb ##
<%= simple_form_for @User do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :username %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
<% end %>

## app/models/user.rb ##
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
end


## app/controllers/users_controller.rb
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.all
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @user, notice: 'User was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    @user.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:username, :password)
    end
end
```

I'm obviously doing something wrong, and I'm pretty sure I will feel like an idiot, but it's my first app :/
Thanks you.
**EDIT:** I forgot to say, I tried (desperately) every vars (@user, @users, @User, @Users), any of them doesn't works :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of the form from the `index.html.erb` view (and no, don't put it in `show.html.erb` either!).

Place this form in the `new.html.erb` view:

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
  <%= f.input :username %>
  <%= f.input :password %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Note that the form should reference `@user` not `@User`.

Comment: and the routes are already made for you when you generated the scaffolding, do not change the routes file.

Comment: Okay, I see what's wrong with all of your comments. I'm not used to Rails yet, and I come from PHP so... I was doing an HUGE mistake. I wasn't able to access `@user` because I wasn't in the right view I guess, I was in the HOME view to create an USER. That's the wrong part, right ?

Comment: yeah you were in the wrong view, you were in the index view which only has the logic to list all users (in the user controller, each function matches with the 1 view that has the same name). are you having more problems? if you got this to work consider marking this as the correct answer

Comment: Yeah, thanks you. I won't do this mistake anymore ! Btw, have you any idea to how to create a signup/signin form on the homepage for example ?

Comment: yeah, you should take a look at a gem called Devise which handles user authentication/autherisation. you can see a video discussing it here: http://railscasts.com/episodes/209-introducing-devise

Comment: Ok, perfect, I'll take a look tomorrow ! Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 1):

Yep ... in the view you are using the `@User` instance variable (with uppercase U) but in the controller you assign the model to the `@user` instance variable (with lowecase u) :)

Comment: I forgot to say, I tried (desperately) every vars (`@user`, `@users`, `@User`, `@Users`), any of them doesn't works :/

Answer (score 1):

Put @user in lowcase (not @user)

```
<%= simple_form_for @user do |f| %>
    <%= f.input :username %>
    <%= f.input :password %>
<% end %>
```

And save it as `new.html.erb` view not `index.html.erb`!

Comment: So, I add `get 'home/show'` to `routes.rb`, I renamed `index.html.erb` to `show.html.erb` and I still have the same error :/