# undefined method `model_name' with simple_form on Rails 5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm getting an  `undefined method 'model_name'` error with simple_form when I want to edit a basic post on Rails 5.

show.html.haml:

`= link_to "Edit", edit_post_path(@post)`

edit.html.haml:

```
= simple_form_for @post do |f|
    = f.input :title
    = f.input :link
    = f.input :description

    = f.button :submit
```

posts_controller.rb:

```
def show
  @post = Post.find(params[:id])
end

def edit
end

def update
  if @post.update(post_params)
    redirect_to @post
  else
    render 'edit'
  end
end
```

Any idea?

Comment: do you have `edit` action in controller?

Comment: yes, see I just edit my post

Comment: add `@post = Post.find(params[:id])` to `edit` action

Comment: thx it's working!

Comment: This would have been far more obvious, had you posted the **full error message** -- Which, presumably, said *"...for `nil:NilClass`"*, implying that your `@post` variable was `nil`.

Comment: [Also](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30542548/rails-undefined-method-model-name-for-nilnilclass?rq=1), [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31868893/rails-undefined-method-model-name-for-nilnilclass?rq=1) [has](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37535332/rails-undefined-method-model-name-for?rq=1) [been](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39403375/rails-undefined-method-model-name-for-nilnilclass-nested-routes?rq=1) [asked](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21841055/simple-form-undefined-method-model-name-for-nilclassclass?rq=1) many times before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def edit
  @post = Post.find(params[:id]) # <=========
end
```